# Stemmed words to compute a frequency plot

Tags: python, pandas, porter-stemmer

I need to plot words frequency:

```
                2333
appartamento    321
casa            314
cè               54 
case             43
                ...
```

However, there are some words having the same stem (then they have a similar meaning). 
In the example above, `casa` and `case` have the same meaning (the first is a singular, the second is a plural name, like `house` and `houses`). 
I read that this issues can be fixed by using `nltk.stem`. I have, therefore, tried as follows:

```
from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer
from nltk.stem import LancasterStemmer

train_df = (df['Frasi'].str.replace(r'[^\w\s]+', '').str.split(' ').value_counts())

porter = PorterStemmer()
lancaster=LancasterStemmer()
```

Now I should run a loop for each word in the list above, using porter and Lancaster, but I do not know how to use the list above to stem. 
Just to give you some context:  the list above comes from phrases/sentences, saved into a dataframe. My dataframe has many columns, including a column `Frasi` where those words come from. 
An example of phrases included within that column is:

```
Frasi
Ho comprato un appartamento in centro
Il tuo appartamento è stupendo
Quanti vani ha la tua casa?
Il mercato immobiliare è in crisi
....
```

What I have tried to do is to clean the sentences, removing punctuation and stop words (but it seems spaces are still in, as shown from the word list above). 
Now I would need to use the information about words frequency to plot the top 10-20 words used, but excluding words with similar meaning or same stem. Should I specify all the suffixes or there is something that I can use to automatise the process?

Any help on this would be great.

Comment: I also looked at  https://tartarus.org/martin/PorterStemmer/, but it is still not clear how I can apply PorterStemmer() to my case

Comment: Should you be using a [French Snowball Stemmer](https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.stem.html)?  Snowball is the Porter stemming algorithms [extended to other languages ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stemming).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [NLTK](https://www.nltk.org/)

**Code**

```
import nltk                                 
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize        # https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python_data_science/python_word_tokenization.htm
from nltk.stem.snowball import SnowballStemmer # https://www.nltk.org/howto/stem.html
from nltk.probability import FreqDist          # http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.html?highlight=freqdist
from nltk.corpus import stopwords              # https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/removing-stop-words-nltk-python/

def freq_dist(s, language):
    " Frequency count based upon language"
    # Language based stops words and stemmer
    fr_stopwords = stopwords.words(language) 
    fr_stemmer = SnowballStemmer(language) 

    # Language based tokenization
    words = word_tokenize(s, language = language)

    return FreqDist(fr_stemmer.stem(w) for w in words if w.isalnum() and not w in fr_stopwords)
```

**Explanation**

Initial data in Pandas DataFrame.  Obtain French column as string.

```
s = '\n'.join(df['French'].tolist())
```

Function `freq_dist` above does the following upon its input string.

Tokenize string based upon language

```
words = word_tokenize(s, language='french')
```

Remove Punctuation (i.e. " ? , . etc.)

```
punctuation_removed = [w for w in words if w.isalnum()]
```

Get French stopwords

```
french_stopwords = set(stopwords.words('french')) # make set for faster lookup
```

Remove stopwords

```
without_stopwords = [w for w in punctuation_removed if not w in french_stopwords]
```

Stem words (which also removes case)

Get French Stemmer and apply stemmer

```
french_stemmer = SnowballStemmer('french')
```

Stem words

```
stemmed_words = [french_stemmer.stem(w) for w in without_stopwords]
```

Frequency distribution using FreqDist

```
fDist = FreqDist(stemmed_words)
```

**Example**

DataFrame:

```
                                      French
0               Ho comprato un appartamento in centro
1                      Il tuo appartamento è stupendo
2                         Quanti vani ha la tua casa?
3                   Il mercato immobiliare è in crisi
4                                     Qui vivra verra
5                        L’habit ne fait pas le moine
6                         Chacun voit midi à sa porte
7                      Mieux vaut prévenir que guérir
8                Petit a petit, l’oiseau fait son nid
9   Qui court deux lievres a la fois, n’en prend a...
10                           Qui n’avance pas, recule
11  Quand on a pas ce que l’on aime, il faut aimer...
12  Il n’y a pas plus sourd que celui qui ne veut ...
```

Generate string

```
sentences = '\n'.join(df['French'].tolist())
```

Generate Word Count

```
counts = freq_dist(sentences, 'french')
```

Show in alphabetical order

```
results = sorted(counts.most_common(), 
                 key=lambda x: x[0])
for k, v in results:
    print(k, v)

a 5
aim 2
appartamento 2
aucun 1
avanc 1
cas 1
celui 1
centro 1
chacun 1
comprato 1
court 1
cris 1
deux 1
entendr 1
fait 2
faut 1
fois 1
guer 1
ha 1
hab 1
ho 1
il 3
immobiliar 1
in 2
l 1
lievr 1
mercato 1
mid 1
mieux 1
moin 1
nid 1
oiseau 1
pet 2
plus 1
port 1
prend 1
préven 1
quand 1
quant 1
qui 3
recul 1
sourd 1
stupendo 1
tu 1
tuo 1
van 1
vaut 1
verr 1
veut 1
vivr 1
voit 1
è 2
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and for going through all the steps providing explanation. I really appreciated it.

Comment: @LucaDiMauro--glad I could help.